# Как упростить регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как упростить регулярное выражение

```
 value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/[()\s-]/g, '').replace(/(?!^)\+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value.replace(/(?:\D|[()\s-]|(?!^)\+)/g, '');
```